# Assign column value (split apply combine) based on another column

Tags: dplyr, split-apply-combine

I have data of format

```
set.seed(40)
subject <- sample(c("mike", "john", "steve"), 20, replace = TRUE)
test1 <- sample(c("pos", "neg", "pos", "neg", "NA"), 20, replace = TRUE)
testdate <- Sys.Date() + sample(-1000:1000, 20, replace = FALSE)
mydf <- data.frame(subject, testdate, test1)
mydf$status <- "unknown"
```

For each subject, I would like to modify the values of status such that: a) it remains unknown until the earliest (by test date) pos or neg result for test1 is obtained; b) when the first pos test1 result is obtained, status on that date and afterwards becomes “in” regardless of any subsequent test1 values; c) if a neg result occurs for test1 before any positive result, status becomes “out” for that and subsequent dates until any positive test1 result is obtained. Open to all solutions. I am experimenting with dplyr and would be especially interested in a dplyr-based solution.

The output would be

```
subject testdate    test1   status
john    2014-11-20  neg negative
john    2015-07-29  neg negative
john    2015-11-10  neg negative
john    2017-04-08  neg negative
john    2018-09-18  NA  negative
mike    2014-09-01  pos positive
mike    2014-10-14  neg positive
mike    2015-03-22  neg positive
mike    2016-09-15  pos positive
mike    2017-08-18  neg positive
mike    2017-12-20  pos positive
mike    2018-09-06  NA  positive
mike    2019-09-02  neg positive
steve   2015-06-21  neg negative
steve   2016-01-03  pos positive
steve   2016-03-12  neg positive
steve   2017-06-26  neg positive
steve   2017-12-02  neg positive
steve   2018-12-20  pos positive
steve   2019-06-20  pos positive
```

Comment: can you please add expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward with `group_by` and `mutate`.

First, modify the test results to be a factor. This allows them to be "ranked" so that we can tell what the "highest" result has been. Because you want the results to be "Missing", "Negative", "Positive", set the levels in that order:

```
mydf$test1 <-
  factor(mydf$test1
         , levels = c("NA", "neg", "pos")
         , ordered = TRUE)
```

Next, create a vector of the labels you want to use when each of the above has happened. In the text, you said you wanted in/out, but the desired output uses Negative/Positive. If you want to change the labels, it should be easy to do that here:

```
statusLevels <-
  c("Unknown", "Negative", "Positive")
```

Finally, we can apply this to the data. First, sort by date to ensure that the test results are checked in the right order (I am also sorting by subject to make the results clear and match your request). Then, group by the the subject. Finally, `mutate` to create the column you want. Here, it checks for the "biggest" test value so far (hence why we converted to a factor) and gives us the status level that matches:

```
mydf %>%
  arrange(subject, testdate) %>%
  group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(status = statusLevels[cummax(as.numeric(test1))])
```

Returns:

```
   subject   testdate test1   status
     <chr>     <date> <ord>    <chr>
1     john 2014-11-21   neg Negative
2     john 2015-07-30   neg Negative
3     john 2015-11-11   neg Negative
4     john 2017-04-09   neg Negative
5     john 2018-09-19    NA Negative
6     mike 2014-09-02   pos Positive
7     mike 2014-10-15   neg Positive
8     mike 2015-03-23   neg Positive
9     mike 2016-09-16   pos Positive
10    mike 2017-08-19   neg Positive
11    mike 2017-12-21   pos Positive
12    mike 2018-09-07    NA Positive
13    mike 2019-09-03   neg Positive
14   steve 2015-06-22   neg Negative
15   steve 2016-01-04   pos Positive
16   steve 2016-03-13   neg Positive
17   steve 2017-06-27   neg Positive
18   steve 2017-12-03   neg Positive
19   steve 2018-12-21   pos Positive
20   steve 2019-06-21   pos Positive
```

Comment: Thanks for this very clean solution - good opportunity for me to learn about the use of ranked factors